# Login Screen and Navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So in my App.Delegate I'm doing this -

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.loginViewController =     [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];



    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.loginViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;


    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and in my login controller I'm doing this -

```
    - (IBAction)login:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *username = self.userName.text;
    NSString *password = self.password.text;

    [AccountUtils emailLogin:username password:password useCookie:true callback:^(NSDictionary *loginResponseJSON){
        if([loginResponseJSON count] != 0){
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displaySearchController) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
           // [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(switchState) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        } else {
        //incorrect entry info view here.

        }

    }];

}

- (void) displaySearchController {
    SearchViewController *searchViewController = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UINavigationController *navigator = self.navigationController;
    [navigator popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    [navigator pushViewController: searchViewController animated:YES];
}
```

If I correctly login, I go to the second controller's view, but at the top I'm still allowed to go 'back' to the login page. I don't want that to happen and I thought this case would be taken care off by the popViewControllerAnimated line. How do I make it so that when I login, I am not allowed to go back to the login page?(in other words, I guess pop the login controller off the navigation controller's stack?)

Answer (score 3):

If you want just to remove the loginVC you could set the new navigationController as the rootViewController of the AppDelegate after the user has logged in. So you could move the `displaySearchController` method in the `AppDelegate` and call this method (from the loginVC) after the user has logged in:

```
-(void)displaySearchController{
    SearchViewController *searchViewController = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: searchViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController=navigation;
}
```

Otherwise, if you really want the push animation, you can remove the loginVC from the navigationController viewControllers stack in the `viewDidAppear` of SearchDispalyController:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  NSMutableArray *stackVCs=[self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
  int idx=[stackVCs indexOfObject:self];
  //this remove the previous viewcontroller from the stack
  [stackVCs removeObjectAtIndex:idx-1];
  self.navigationController.viewControllers=stackVCs;
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Also in the loginVC just before push the searchVC you should call this to hide the back button:
 `[navigation.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a UINavigationController with the LoginViewController and you don't want to push the SearchViewController.  Instead, use a UINavigationController with SearchViewController and when you display it, make it the rootViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to achieve what you want.

1. Move the `displaySearchController` method to your `AppDelegate.m` file
2. Do declare the `displaySearchController` method in `AppDelegate.h` file
3. Now Define the `displaySearchController` method in `AppDelegate.m` file as :

   ```
   - (void) displaySearchController {
       SearchViewController *searchViewController = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
       UINavigationController *navigator = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:searchViewController];
       self.window.rootViewController = navigator;             
   }
   ```

Call a new local method `showNewViewController` from your `loginController` as :

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showNewViewController) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Now define `showNewViewController` in your `loginController.m` file as

```
-(void)showNewViewController {
    AppDelegate *appDele = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appDele displaySearchController];
}
```

Don't forget to import the `AppDelegate.h` file to your `loginController.m`

This will certainly help you.